# how to make background color for footer in rmarkdown using Latex?

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

I want to add background color to my footer as shown below.
[image]

I'm not getting background color i added to my footer but it didn't work. below code only generates footer. how to get output as shown above making backgroundcolor

```
---
title: "123"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
classoption: svgnames
header-includes:
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead{}
- \fancyfoot{} 
- \lfoot[LE,LO]{ABCDEFGHIJ 2020 1.3.4}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}

---
```

Comment: please make a compilable [mre] and it would also be useful if you could add the intermediate .tex file to your question (you can generate it by adding `keep_tex: true` to your header)

Comment: Should the colour only span the width and height of the footer or extend to the page borders?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz, looking forward to your answer :)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz please check i have updated. you can see the image above i want some thing like that. it should not exceed page broders.

Comment: @Anu If you `fancyhdr` version is up to date, you can simplify the last line of your header to `\fancypagestyle{plain}[fancy]{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick way to add a coloured box the footer with tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{} 
\lfoot[LE,LO]{\tikz{\node[white,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=10pt,fill=blue!70,text width=\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt\relax,align=left] at (0,0) {ABCDEFGHIJ 2020 1.3.4};}}
\setlength{\footskip}{30.44pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}

\begin{document}

text

\end{document}
```

or in rmarkdown:

```
---
title: "123"
output:
  pdf_document: 
    keep_tex: true
classoption: svgnames
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{fancyhdr}
- \pagestyle{fancy}
- \fancyhead{}
- \fancyfoot{} 
- \lfoot[LE,LO]{\tikz{\node[white,outer sep=0pt,inner sep=10pt,fill=blue!70,text width=\dimexpr\textwidth-20pt\relax,align=left] at (0,0) {ABCDEFGHIJ 2020 1.3.4};}}
- \setlength{\footskip}{30.44pt}
- \fancypagestyle{plain}{\pagestyle{fancy}}
---

test
```

[image]

(The advantage of using tikz for this job is that adjusting the padding around the text gets really easy)

Answer (score 1):

You could use LaTeX code. Here is an example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "bttomio"
date: "5/1/2021"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{xcolor}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an example^[\textcolor{white}{\colorbox{blue}{Example in a R Markdown document.}}]
````

-output

[image]